# Can i use & variable of sed for doing operation inside $()?

Tags: sed

I am not sure whether the below statement can be done placing & inside $() so that each
time & is replaced by 1,2,3,4 and 1 is added to it.

```
echo 1 2 3 4 | tr ' ' '\n' | sed "s/.*/$(echo expr 1 + &)/"
```

The above statement doesn't work

i get the output :

```
expr 1 +
expr 1 +
expr 1 +
expr 1 +
```

Comment: You might, perhaps, with considerable effort and command line gymnastics manage to do so, but if you need to do this you are almost certainly doing something wrong. What is the [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101) you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't *need* to use `sed` for this, here are a few other options:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 | tr ' ' '\n' | while read f; do let f+=1; echo $f; done
2
3
4
5
$ echo 1 2 3 4 | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{print $1+1}'
2
3
4
5
$ echo 1 2 3 4 | tr ' ' '\n' | perl -lne '$i=$_+1; print $i'
2
3
4
5
```

`sed` is a stream editor, it is not supposed to do mathematical expressions.